# Converting Unicode-escaped characters with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

Can anyone say how I convert Unicode code point escaped characters like `\u00e4` to the real character `ö` in XSLT?

I do have...

```
<text>Eine Repr\u00e4sentation des Objektes geh\u00f6rt...<text>
```

...and I like to have:

```
<text>Eine Repräsentation des Objektes gehört...<text>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 would be great, but XSLT 2.0 is fine, too.

Comment: How many different characters are escaped that way? Do you have a comprehensive list, are there, say, only 3 occurrences in total, always the same character? Only umlauts?

Comment: For what it's worth, there's code to do the reverse here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/xml-to-json.xsl. You might need to think about how to handle surrogate pairs, where two consecutive \uxxxx escape sequences represent a high surrogate and low surrogate, which need to be combined into a single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a fun thing to do... so here's a XSLT 2.0 solution that I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math f"
    xmlns:f="func" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="f:unescapeCharachters(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:unescapeCharachters">
        <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="\\u([0-9|abcdefABCDEF]{{4}})">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(f:hex-to-dec(regex-group(1)))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="f:hex-to-dec">
        <xsl:param name="hex"/>
        <xsl:variable name="hexvals" select="'0123456789ABCDEF'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$hex=''">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="string-length(substring-before($hexvals,substring(upper-case($hex),1,1)))
                * math:pow(16,string-length($hex)-1) + f:hex-to-dec(substring($hex,2))"
                />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice, though you probably don't really want to pass `text()` to the top-level function call as you'll get a type mismatch error if the `text` element has more than one text node child.  Probably better to have a template that matches `text/text()` and passes `.` to the function.

Comment: @IanRoberts thanks for the hint, your right...just didn't think of it for the example, updated my answer.