# XML-HTML Transformation of unicode characters using Transformer in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt, unicode

I am using Java.xml.Transformer in Android class to transform my xml to html using a XSLT, the problem is that it(XML) contains some math unicode(ex:&#x2110) characters which were transformed into unknown garbage characters which is shown as below

[image]

i have checked the xml source and the transformation takes place at the Transformer.transform place is there any way to get the content right.

This is the tag inside the xml:

```html
</italic>.</p> 
        <p><italic>j</italic>: index of orders, <italic>j</italic> &#x2208; <italic>&#x1D4A5;</italic>.</p> 
        <p><italic>p</italic>: index of products, <italic>p</italic> &#x2208; <italic>&#x1D4AB;</italic>.</p>
        <p>&#160;</p>
```

The above code rendered here correctly as below
.

j: index of orders, j ∈ 𝒥.

p: index of products, p ∈ 𝒫.

this is what i found for this tag in xsl:

Comment: Using which XSLT code? Can you show that stylesheet?

Comment: Does the XSLT matters here? i suspect the Transformer Class of the android package.i think XSLT doest change the content in my case it just adds styling. if you still prefer to see  XSLT i will provide.

Comment: As a rule for all software development, you should be more inclined to question your own code than an official, tested library. If you show the XML input and stylesheet, we can try and reproduce your issue.

Comment: xml https://www.dropbox.com/s/0odl7w09waurlud/orsc.2013.0856.xml?dl=0 xsl https://www.dropbox.com/s/otvaa73rpri5dcs/jpub3-html-trans.xsl?dl=0 @MathiasMüller

Comment: Please do not link to your code, but edit your question. Oh, and also [create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Unicode-escaped characters with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490738/converting-unicode-escaped-characters-with-xslt)